# Determining whether there is significant difference between the mean of a variable in your study with the mean of the same variable in another study

Tags: t-test, mean

If you work on a cross-sectional study which does not contain controls and you want to compare the mean of a certain variable in your cases with the mean of the same variable for controls in another study, how do you know whether there is significant difference between cases and control? Could it be done using a statistical test or does it necessitate just comparing the two numbers without any test.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if they are statistically different, then you need to use a statistical test.

But, if it is simply the question "are the means the same?", then it is the most basic test - just a t-test.